# How to get text box data of a table from a ng-repeat to an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

```
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 45%; color: black; text-decoration: underline"><b>Inter Equalent Education</b></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Group Name: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selintergroup">
          <option selected="selected" value="">-Select-</option>
          <option data-ng-repeat="inter in intergroup" value="{{inter.grp_code}}">{{inter.grp_name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>Academic Year</th>
        <th>Roll No</th>
        <th>Institue Name</th>
        <th>Marks Secured</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="p in ipeedata">
        <td>{{p.edu_dur}}</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="tableinteracayear" maxlength="7" style="text-transform: uppercase" /></td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="tableinterrollno" maxlength="10" style="text-transform: uppercase" /></td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="tableinterinsname" maxlength="75" style="text-transform: uppercase" /></td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="tableintermarks" maxlength="75" style="text-transform: uppercase" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <%--INTER div--%>
</div>
```

JS

```
scope.interarr.push({
  duration: scope.ipeedata[0].edu_dur,
  academicyear: scope.tableinteracayear,
  rollno: scope.tableinterrollno,
  institutename: scope.tableinterinsname,
  markssecured: scope.tableintermarks
})
```

it is showing only 1 row that is entered first in the table,but i want all the rows data into this array

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `ng-model` directives relative to the `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="p in ipeedata">
    <td>{{p.edu_dur}}</td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" 
               type="text" 
               data-ng-model="p.tableinteracayear" 
               maxlength="7" 
               style="text-transform: uppercase" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" 
               type="text" 
               data-ng-model="p.tableinterrollno" 
               maxlength="10" 
               style="text-transform: uppercase" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" 
               type="text" 
               data-ng-model="p.tableinterinsname" 
               maxlength="75" 
               style="text-transform: uppercase" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" 
               type="text" 
               data-ng-model="p.tableintermarks" 
               maxlength="75" 
               style="text-transform: uppercase" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then you will be able to put those values into your `$scope` variable:

```
$scope.interarr = $scope.ipeedata.map((item) => {
    let interarr = {
        duration = item.edu_dur,
        academicyear = item.tableinteracayear,
        rollno: item.tableinterrollno,
        institutename: item.tableinterinsname,
        markssecured: item.tableintermarks
    };
    return interarr;
}
```